# Make nav-item active, Vuejs and Bootstrap-Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I am using bootstrap-vue, and I have a b-nav,and when I am on a specific route the nav-item is active, in my case I have some links with params, so there it is inactive.

```
  <b-nav tabs justified class="pr-4 pl-4">
    <b-nav-item :to="{ name: 'Clauses' }" exact exact-active-class="active">
      <h4>Clauses</h4>
    </b-nav-item>
  </b-nav-item>
```

In this case my url can be like this `clause?page=1&search=example` ,so I won't have any active links. I know that `exact` is use for exact path, but In my case I am not sure what can I use. The question is, how can I make routes active even with params?

Answer (score 0):

I fount the solution.

Remove `exact exact-` from each `exact exact-active-class="active"` ,and will work.